# Search in a directory a file with the length equal or greater than a given int in c language in windows

Tags: c, windows, named-pipes, filesize

I am trying to make a named Windows pipe in C. The pipe is used by a user and a server. The user sends trough the pipe a random int. Then the server searches in its current directory a file with the size greater or equal with the received int, and then sends back to the user the file name and a maximum of 100 bytes from the file.

My problem is that i don't know how to verify the size of every file from the directory, and then to return the filename and 100 bytes.

This is the function i'm trying to use for measuring a file size:

> ```
> int fsize(char* file)
> {
>     FILE * f = fopen(file, "r");
>     fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
>     int len = (unsigned long)ftell(f);
>     fclose(f);
>     return len;
> }
> ```

This is the "client" code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#define MAXLINIE 100
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char rcvMsg[100];
    char sndMsg[100];
    DWORD rez;
    HANDLE readHandle, writeHandle;

    int r = rand();
    char str[15];
    sprintf(str, "%d", r);

    writeHandle = CreateFile("\\\\.\\PIPE\\FirstPipe", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                   NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

    readHandle = CreateFile("\\\\.\\PIPE\\SecondPipe",GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ,
                   NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

    strcpy(sndMsg, r);
    printf("Sending message to server: %s\n", sndMsg);
    WriteFile(writeHandle, sndMsg, strlen(sndMsg), &rez, NULL);
    printf("Message sent! Waiting for server to read the message!\n");

    printf("Waiting for SERVER to write in the pipe...\n");
    ReadFile(readHandle, rcvMsg, 100, &rez, NULL);  
    printf("Client revceived message: %s\n", rcvMsg);

    CloseHandle(readHandle);
    CloseHandle(writeHandle);

    return 1;

}
```

This is the "server" code, excepting the file parsing part:

>

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#define MAXLINIE 100

    //file lenght
int fsize(char* file)
    {
    FILE * f = fopen(file, "r");
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    int len = (unsigned long)ftell(f);
    fclose(f);
    return len;
    }


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char rcvMsg[100];
    char sndMsg[100];
    DWORD rez;
    HANDLE readHandle, writeHandle;

    readHandle = CreateNamedPipe("\\\\.\\PIPE\\FirstPipe", PIPE_ACCESS_INBOUND, 
                        PIPE_TYPE_BYTE|PIPE_WAIT,3,0,0,0,NULL);

    writeHandle = CreateNamedPipe("\\\\.\\PIPE\\SecondPipe", PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND,
                        PIPE_TYPE_BYTE|PIPE_WAIT, 3, 0, 0, 0, NULL);    

    printf("Waiting for clients to connect...\n");
    ConnectNamedPipe(writeHandle, NULL);
        ConnectNamedPipe(readHandle, NULL);

    printf("Waiting for a CLIENT to write in the pipe...\n");
    ReadFile(readHandle, rcvMsg, 100, &rez, NULL);  
    printf("Server revceived message: %s\n", rcvMsg);

    int num = atoi(rcvMsg); //the file lenght i'm looking for

    //here i should process the files

    strcpy(sndMsg, "File_name + 100 bytes");
    printf("Server sends an answer: %s\n", sndMsg);
    WriteFile(writeHandle, sndMsg, strlen(sndMsg), &rez, NULL);
    printf("Waiting for client to read the message...\n");

    // disconnecting and closing the handles
    DisconnectNamedPipe(writeHandle);
    CloseHandle(writeHandle);

    DisconnectNamedPipe(readHandle);
    CloseHandle(readHandle);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: ***[GetFileSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364955%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)***  Or, an even better option:  ***[FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)***  (More efficient)

Comment: but are them working in C? i found them too... but it says "C++"...

Comment: See example below.  I just compiled it just as it is in my C compiler.  Look in the wfd struct for file attributes.  Of course, make sure you pass it your own directory path :)

Comment: Any feedback Tripon - Is this working for you?

Answer (score 0):

FindFirstFile() and FindNextFile() to iterate through files... supports wildcards. When done call FindClose()
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is example code using FindFirstFile from ***[cprogramming](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/windows-programming/9628-searching-file-using-findfirstfile.html)***:   (look in wfd struct for size attributes)

***see other comments below code example***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

void find(char* path,char* file)  //Note: pass the path string appropriate for your scenario
{
    static int found =0;
    HANDLE fh;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA wfd;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    fh=FindFirstFile(path,&wfd);
    if(fh)
    {
        if(strcmp(wfd.cFileName,file)==0)
        {
            path[strlen(path)-3]='\0';
            strcat(path,file);
            FindClose(fh);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            while(FindNextFile(fh,&wfd) && found ==0)
            {              
                if(strcmp(wfd.cFileName,file)==0)
                {
                    path[strlen(path)-3]='\0';
                    strcat(path,file);
                    FindClose(fh);
                    found =1;
                    return;
                }
                if(wfd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY &&
                    strcmp(wfd.cFileName,"..")!=0 && strcmp(wfd.cFileName,".")!=0)
                {
                    path[strlen(path)-3]='\0';
                    strcat(path,wfd.cFileName);
                    strcat(path,"\\*.*");
                    find(path,file);
                }
            }

            if(found==0)
                {
                for(i=strlen(path)-1;i>0;i--)
                {
                    if(j==1 && path[i]=='\\')
                    {
                        path[i]='\0';
                        strcat(path,"\\*.*");
                        break;
                    }
                    if(path[i]=='\\')
                        j=1;
                }
            }
        }
        FindClose(fh);
    }



}

int main()
{
    TCHAR path[512] = "C:\\*.*";  //Change this as necessary 
    find(path,"notepad.exe");
    printf("%s\n",path);

    return 0;
}
```

The file attributes will ***give you the file name, and size*** etc.

You can ***then write the 100 bytes to a char buffer*** by passing the name and path of the found file to `fopen()`: `FILE *fp = fopen(fileNamePath, "r");`  Then something like char buf[101];for(i=0;i<100;i++){buf[i] = fgetc(fp);}
***Don't forget to use `fclose()` when you are done with `fp`.

Comment: i'm a begginer in c... so it's hard to understand what is going on in the code above, but i will try again... thx anyway. or if you can explain me in some words what it does it would help me a lot.

Comment: @TriponIonut - Your original question was how to determine the size of a found file, then return the first n bytes, where n is an input to  the calling function, I believe.  The `FindFirstFile()` and `FindNextFile()` functions [almost] always work in conjunction with each other, and together, will provide the information you ask for.  The code example I provided (and link) provide details sufficient to get you going with a little effort.  If you have another question, please post it, with some example code showing your effort, and I would bet there will be 10 views within the first hour.